# How to create a dashed line rounded rectangle in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, graphics, drawing, rounded-corners

How can I create a rounded rectangle with a dashed line?  I've seen several routines that draw their own straight lines, but nothing for rounded rectangles.

Comment: flex 3 or 4? and is this for a skin?

Answer (score 1):

There used to be (probably still is) a great AS 2/3 library for this but I can't find it.

This looks pretty promising:

[http://blog.alegitimatebusiness.com/2007/11/07/as2-as3-draw-a-dotted-rounded-corner-box](http://blog.alegitimatebusiness.com/2007/11/07/as2-as3-draw-a-dotted-rounded-corner-box/)/